# Check valid values of an option (e.g. check if completeopt+=popup is valid)

Tags: vimscript, options

I want to know if I can use the `popup` option for my `completeopt` in the running version of vim/neovim. The example is just for clarity, I'm looking for a solution that is generic.

I know I *can* check `exists("&completeopt")`, or check if a value already is set within it (`&completeopt ~=# 'popup'`).

What I don't know is how to check for valid values within an option like `completeopt`, `guioptions`, etc. if that option is not already set with that value.

I can't find any answer or help under `:h exists`, or any of the other vi.stackexchange or stackoverflow answers using search terms "check valid values for option". I have read the suggestions [on this webpage about graceful option degrading](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/gracefully-degrading-vimrc/)

I'm aware I could use a `try ... catch` block, but would rather avoid that extra code and incompatibility with vim < 7 (for the purposes of completeness)

For this specific example, I could use `v:version > 802`, but I'm interested in an approach targeted to a specific feature, so that I can re-use it for other options and so that it works for neovim.

Edit: Reading the online docs for version 8.2, I see it specifies the compile-requirement of `textprop`, so I assume I could do `has('textprop')`. However, I would still very much like to know if there is a more generic way to do it, to make doing the same for other options easier and more robust (in case of incorrect/missing documentation, or compile-invariant options)

Edit 2: `textprop` is present in versions prior to those that introduced `popup`, so doesn't work.

Comment: I am not aware of a generic feature check for valid option values. Best would probably to check the version/patch that introduced this feature.

Comment: Thank you, coming from you I'm sure I won't get any better answer. Do you know of a way to easily find the patch that introduced a specific feature?

Comment: `git log --grep completeopt` shows this has been added at vim 8.1.1880